# Can "like that" be the same as "is that so"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> X: Susan will be married in June.
>
> Y: **Like that**. I don't care

I'm trying to find a phrase/word that can fit in there, but it seems "like that" sound awkward to my ear. It's an expression that's said by the speaker **Y** to confirm that he's understand what **X** is talking about. However, it must have a decreased tone instead of an increased tone. Perhaps, similar to *is that so*, but I'm afraid that's not what I want here because it has an increased tone in my view. What is your suggestion?

Thaks in advance!

Comment: "So what?" would be idiomatic here (meaning 'What does that matter to me?')

Comment: I couldn't care less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a set-up like you've described it seems like you're trying to make both parts of Y's line mean the same thing.

"So what", strongly implies I don't care. Where as "Is that so", is an expression that could go either way. "Is that so? Very interesting".

Alternatives for negative

> I couldn't care less.
> I could care less. (American - yes it literally means something different)
> Bothered.

Alternatives for neutral

> Really?
> Will she?

Note that the negatives are statements while the neutrals are questions.